# database relation of score up and down, Like the stackoverflow one?

Tags: php, mysql

How to create database relation of score up and down, Like the stackoverflow one?

The same way like no same user can vote for their own questions and other people can only vote for one, either negative or positive.

Let say the question I added is having `question_id = 25` and my `user_id=04`.
and there are 3 other users with `user_id =01, 02, 03` respectively.

Now user_id = 04 cannot vote a question with question_id = 25. (its fine)

I want users with user_id = 01 , 02 , 03 to vote.

Will it be like each row to be created for each vote in the database ?

```
question_id     user_id
  25               01
  25               02
  25               03
```

To keep in check whether a user has voted for a question or not ?

or is there a way to accommodate voters user_id in a same field ?

```
question_id      user_id
    25          01, 02, 03
```

is it feasible ? Please reply if you got a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* use comma-separated values in a field.

```
CREATE TABLE Votes (
    question_id int unsigned,
    user_id int unsigned,
    vote boolean null default null,
    unique key (question_id, user_id)
);
```

This schema will prevent multiple `question_id`,`user_id` entries.

When a user creates a question, you can create a `Votes` entry with a `NULL` value that will prevent another entry but also means no vote.  For others, `1` and `0` could be "up" and "down" votes.

If there's one thing you should take away from my answer it is *avoid comma-separated values in fields*.

Comment: Not to use comma separated values is fine...bt what should i do? If i use the other way it will be the flood of rows and surely a bad approach

Comment: @Aayush not at all; There is no problem with having a large number of rows.  That's kind of the point of a Database.  If you're really concerned about that, maybe you should use another storage platform like MongoDB

Comment: can you explain how can i use your schema? i mean if a question_id and user_id will be unique key, then how come i can make it sure that only one time a user can vote ? sorry i can't understand your logic

Comment: @Aayush say that you have question ID 1 and user ID 1.  `(1,1)` is unique, so you can only have one row (i.e. one vote per use per question)